# Android dark theme convert my colour from white to black

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

I want to set Tint to drawable with white colour and I don't what colour to change when I change my application to dark theme so I declare my colour like this.

```
values/colors.xml
   <color name="white_force">#ffffff</color>

values-night/colors.xml
   <color name="white_force">#ffffff</color>
   

ic_drawable.xml
   <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="14dp"
    android:height="18dp"
    android:viewportWidth="14"
    android:viewportHeight="18">
        <path
            android:pathData="M12,......,3V15Z"
            android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
    </vector>

layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bookmarkImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/ds2_space_2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark_white_14" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but when I set Tint to my drawable when I change my app to dark mode it set colour t0 black instead of white.

Comment: Why you are using same color code in both type

Comment: Hello! Can you verify if you are add some color value inside your drawable file.

Comment: @AnkurRohilla I want a same colour for both theme.

Comment: @rguzman I can verify that I'm not add any colours inside my drawable file. But I'm not sure if it because my dribble is a vector.

Comment: Can you add the code of your drawable and the file where you add color_white?

Comment: @rguzman Ok, I already add those to my code.

Comment: Can you try something like this:
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="14dp"
    android:height="18dp"
    android:viewportWidth="14"
    android:viewportHeight="18"
    android:tint="@android:color/white">
    <path
        android:pathData="M12,......,3V15Z"
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"/>
</vector>

Comment: @rguzman I already try that, but it don't work. Anyway thank for your recommend :)

Comment: Ok, Can you add all the xml file where you use ic_drawable?

Comment: @rguzman Ok, I add my view_layout.

Comment: It seems your are using "tools:src" instead of "app:srcCompat" or "android:src". Also, before you install the app check if you parent theme is "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar". Finally, try to clean the project,  uninstall the app and install again.